# Push function for LinkedList

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a Linked-List and trying to use malloc effeciently. I have created a container structure and a node structure. The node structure has 2 members data and address of the next node. The container structure will hold the length, capacity of the list. It will also have 2 more members head and tail of type node. These members will hold the information of head and tail.

I have created a create_list list function which will create an empty list with 'capacity' number of nodes. I have to design a push function. This push function should populate the existing nodes first. As the user keeps pushing data the length increases. When length is equal to capacity the push function should create another node and add to the list.

My work so far

```
struct Node
{
    uint8_t data;
    struct Node *next;
};

//LinkedList Container Structure
struct lllifo_s
{
    int length;
    int capacity;
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
};

typedef struct lllifo_s lllifo_t;

lllifo_t *lllifo_create(int size)
{
    struct lllifo_s *list = (struct lllifo_s*)malloc(sizeof(struct lllifo_s));

        if (list == NULL) {
                // Handle allocation failure
                return NULL;
            }

            struct Node* first = NULL;

            //initialization
            list->length = 0;
            list->capacity = size;
            list->head = NULL;
            list->tail = NULL;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                struct Node *newnode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

                newnode->data = 1;
                newnode->next = NULL;

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    list->head = newnode;
                    list->tail = newnode;
                    first = newnode;
                }
                else
                {
                    first->next = newnode;
                    first = newnode;
                }
            }
            first->next = NULL;
        return list;
}



int lllifo_push(struct lllifo_s *lifo, uint8_t element) {
    if (lifo->length < lifo->capacity) {

         if (lifo->length == 0)
         {
              lifo->head->data = element
         }

        else
         {
        lifo->tail->data = (uint8_t)element; //getting a hardfault
        lifo->tail = lifo->tail->next;
          }
        
        lifo->length++;
    } else {
        lifo->tail->data = element;
        lifo->tail->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        lifo->tail = lifo->tail->next;
        lifo->tail->data = 0;
        lifo->tail->next = NULL;
        lifo->capacity++;
        lifo->length++;
    }
    return lifo->length;
}
```

However, when I try to enqueue data. I am getting a hardfault.
I tried to debug it and I noticed that the data isn't getting updated. I don't know why is this happening!

While debugging I noticed some sort of interrupt is also being generated.Can that be the reason for an hardfault?

[image]

Comment: will your `head` and `tail` always point to first node after calling `lllifo_create`?

Comment: Tip: go for a simple LL without "pre-allocated" nodes. The code is clear and easy to understand.

Comment: @madhvi burange – Your _work_ is incomplete and, what's more, not compilable: `In function 'lllifo_push': error: expected ';' before '}' token`.

Comment: Missing includes.

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `lifo->tail` when `lifo->length` becomes equal to `lifo->capacity` ? After the first `lifo->length++;` add `if (lifo->length == lifo->capacity) printf("tail is now %p\n", lifo->tail);`

Comment: _t names are reserved in POSIX and your triple lll prefix would drive me nuts if I had to look at that.

Comment: Also... Look close to where the first two push will save data

Comment: Don't cast the void * from malloc.

Answer (score 0):

I used consistent naming of your types (lower case), and dropped the `_s` and `_t` suffix as the latter is reserved in POSIX.  It's also not needed (the struct name requires the `struct` keyword).

(Not fixed) For library code, like data structures, use the same prefix for all public symbols, i.e. `lllnode` instead of just `node` to avoid conflicts as your projects grow.

(Not fixed) How do you want to handle `malloc()` failing with `NULL` when allocating a node?

The main thing that is tripping you up, I think, is what `lllifo.tail` should point to.  I suggest the last used node which means it should be set to `NULL` in `lllifo_create()`.

I used a `struct node **c`, it looks fancy, but it's basically just a way to avoid repeating myself.  In `lllifo_create()` I initialize it to `list->first` then use it to point to the current node we allocating.  In `lllifo_push()` when out of space if we have a `lifo->tail` then we need the new node to be `tail->next` otherwise we don't have any nodes and we are allocating the first node which means we need set `lifo->head`.

In `lllifo_push()` if we deal with adding capacity first then it's the same code to actually add the new element.

(Not fixed) Add a function to free the memory you allocated for your `lllinfo` instance(s).

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3

typedef struct node {
    uint8_t data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct lllifo {
    int length;
    int capacity;
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
} lllifo;

lllifo *lllifo_create(size_t size) {
    lllifo *list = malloc(sizeof *list);
    if (!list)
        return NULL;
    list->length = 0;
    list->capacity = size;

    if(!size) {
        list->head = NULL;
        list->tail = NULL;
        return list;
    }
    struct node **c = &list->head;
    for(; size; size--, c = &(*c)->next)
        *c = malloc(sizeof *c);
    *c = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    return list;
}

int lllifo_push(lllifo *lifo, uint8_t element) {
    lifo->length++;
    if(lifo->length > lifo->capacity) {
        node **c = lifo->tail ? &lifo->tail->next : &lifo->head;
        *c = malloc(sizeof *lifo->tail);
        (*c)->next = NULL;
        lifo->capacity++;
    }
    lifo->tail = lifo->tail ? lifo->tail->next : lifo->head;
    lifo->tail->data = element;
    return lifo->length;
}

void lllifo_print(lllifo *lifo) {
    for(node *c = lifo->head; c; c = c->next)
        printf("%" PRId8 "%s", c->data, c->next ? "->" : "\n");
}

int main(void) {
    lllifo *c = lllifo_create(N);
    if(!c) return 1;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 2 * N; i++)
        lllifo_push(c, i);
    lllifo_print(c);
}
```

Here is the output (we pre-allocate N = 3, but push 6 elements so we exercise the capacity expansion code path in `lllinfo_push()`):

```
0->1->2->3->4->5
```